# Does using subquery to select specific columns in from clause efficient?

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

Suppose table1 has column a,b,c,.....z.

Does selecting specific columns using sub-query in from clause perform better than 
just selecting all(*)?

OR does it result in more calculations?
( I am using HIVE)

A)

```
select
    table1.a,
    table1.b,
    table2.aa,
    table2.bb

FROM (SELECT table1.a
               ,table1.b
            FROM table1
       )

   join table2 on  (table1.b = table2.b)




B)
select
    table1.a,
    table1.b,
    table2.aa,
    table2.bb

   FROM table1 

   join table2 on  (table1.b = table2.b)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can check performance(time taken) of both queries by executing them one by one.

Comment: No difference. Optimizer will take care about optimal query plan. BTW the subquery should have an alias.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN command and compare query plans

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery to select specific columns is generally a bad idea, regardless of the database.  However, in most databases, it make no difference to performance.

Why is it a bad idea?  Basically, it can confuse the optimizer and/or anyone reading the query.  Depending on the database,

- It makes queries a bit harder to maintain (adding a new column can require repeating the column name over and over in subqueries).
- The subqueries might be materialized (this should not occur in Hive).
- Pruning partitions may not work if the pruning is in outer queries.
- It may preclude the use of indexes (does not apply to Hive).
- It may confuse the optimizer and statistics (probably does not apply to Hive).

I cannot think of a good reason for actually complicating a query by introducing unnecessary subqueries for this purpose.